# Keyboard Layout resets on every startup

Tags: 11.04, kubuntu, kdm

I want to use "German, no dead keys" (as "tot" as the layout. Whenever I log into KDE from KDM, I get the regular "German" keyboard. In other questions here I read that you have to switch the keyboard in the login screen, but apparently KDM does not offer that option.

Interstingly, it show "tot" in the systray when I log in, but then switches to "de" once the jingle plays.

What can I do about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Maybe**

Sometimes the KDE setting files get damaged. Then the KDE will fall to the sane default settings.

**Test**

1. Make a new user. System Settings > User Management
2. Log in as the new user

Does the new user have the same problem ?

**If no**

Rename (/remove) the old user's  ~/.kde/share/config/kxkbrc file when the old user's session is not running.

**Here**

Here the "eliminate dead key" seems to work without problems.

[image]

Comment: I deleted the config file, created it new and it seems like it works. What happens now is that KDE freezes for some 5 seconds before playing the welcome jingle and letting me do anything … that started to happen on a second account some while ago too …